# Honeycomb dim status bar + minSdkVersion in manifest < 11

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I try to dim status bar on Honeycomb, it works as adviced eslewhere using this call

```
View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN)
```

Problem is that it works only if manifest has android:minSdkVersion="11".

I would like to support devices since API ver 7, and still be able to dim status bar if it is present.

Is there some magical combination of setup making this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, problem spotted and fixed after a while:

My manifest missed (actually had badly typed) **android:targetSdkVersion="11"**. When setting this, status bar gets dimmed, and minSdkVersion can be < 11 as desired.

Comment: I did that and it works for me, on android 14. But I still doesn't understand why changing the target makes it works. Any one knows?

Comment: @Derzu because this method was defined in Honeycomb, i.e. SDK version >= 11. When you set targetSDK lower than 11, your IDE uses older SDK to compile your project and hence cannot find this method and gives you an error. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ponter Null, you forgot to provide source code.
To avoid crashes on pre-HONEYCOMB, you should use such `if`-statement:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            View.setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```